# SQL update each row value (old value + parameter) with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedures from a C# program. I need that procedure to create a new table with the values from an old table, that is the easy part.

The hard part is to update all the values in the new table with a parameter. All values in my new table have to look like this

```
new_value = (parameter + old_value)
```

I tried the following by myself, but the syntax is wrong, can you please help me out

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[combine_one_with_all_opponent]
(
   @tblname sysname,
   @value nchar(6)
)
AS
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) = NULL

    SELECT @sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' + quotename(@tblname) +
                  'SELECT _Value INTO ' + quotename(@tblname) + 
                  'FROM dbo.tbl_comm_cards

                   UPDATE ' + quotename(@tblname) + 
                  'SET _Value = ( ' + @value +' + _Value)'

    EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: ColumnName(s) and DataType(s) for `CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: ColumName = _Value DataType = nchar(12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `CREATE TABLE` from your query

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[combine_one_with_all_opponent]
(
@tblname sysname,
@value nchar(6)
)
AS
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

    SELECT @sql='SELECT _Value INTO ' + quotename(@tblname) + '
    FROM dbo.tbl_comm_cards opp

    UPDATE ' + @tblname +'
                SET _Value = ( ''' + @value +''' + _Value)'

    EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Error in sql query incorrect syntax near A2A (the input value is 1A2A)

Comment: I was expecting that the _Value column is numeric, but since it is nchar(12) just try to enclose the @value with '''

Comment: Can you try the code again? Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Invalid Column Name _Value :(

Comment: Is the column _Value exists in dbo.tbl_comm_cards?  If not then what column from that table are you trying to insert into the new table?

Comment: It exists and it is the only Colum in the table

Comment: Are you expecting an output from the stored procedure? If you only need to update the values from the new table it should have been updated by now.

Comment: I expect as output a new table with the name from parameter tblname. In this table i expect a colum with name _Value, in _Value i expect all the data from the old table + my input value. Your code does not create a table so i wonder how this could work anyway ;)

Comment: If you are expecting select result then just add a select onto the query SELECT _Value FROM ' + quotename(@tblname)

Comment: The SELECT INTO statement should automatically create your new table http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: I wrote in my last comment what I expect. I dont just expect a select result ;)

Comment: I guess it would create a new table, but it runs into the Invalid Column Name Error first

Comment: If it is an invalid column then it only means one thing "the column _Value does not exists in dbo.tbl_comm_cards"

Comment: Well it works now. I guess the problem came from my program. Thank you a lot!